# Why resolve does not work in angular ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I want to pass data from factory in resolve property in angular ui-router. I have added the resolve key named "alltasks" in the   TasksController controller. But an error is shown like http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=alltasksProvider

```
$stateProvider.state('task',
   {
    url:'/task',        
    views:{
        "sidebar":{
            templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskcreateform.html',
            controller:"TasksController",
        },
        "content":{
            templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskgrid.html',
            controller:"TasksController",
            resolve:{
                alltasks:function(Task){
                Task.query(function(data){
                return data;
                 });
                }
            }
        }
    }           
});
```

And my Controller is :

```
myApp.controller("TasksController",
 ["$scope","$filter","$interval","$timeout","$http","$httpParamSerializerJQLike","Task","toaster","$stateParams","alltasks",
  function($scope,$filter,$interval,$timeout,$http,$httpParamSerializerJQLike,Task,toaster,$stateParams,alltasks){

  $scope.tasks=alltasks; //data from ui-router Resolve property
  $scope.appname="Test App";
  $scope.task={status:'pending'};
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both views share the same controller, but only one view is provided with that 
resolve. So, let's move it on a state (not named view) level

```
$stateProvider
   .state('task',
   {
    url:'/task',
    views:{

        "sidebar":{
            templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskcreateform.html',
            controller:"TasksController",
        },
        "content":{
            templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskgrid.html',
            controller:"TasksController",
            // this resolve would be available just for this view
            //resolve:{
            //    alltasks:function(Task){
            //    Task.query(function(data){
            //    return data;
            //     });
            //    }
            //}
        }
    },
    // this resolve should be ready for any controller
    // of any named view
    resolve:{
        alltasks:function(Task){
        Task.query(function(data){
        return data;
         });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Brother @Radim Köhler
I have changed my code as like you mention above, the error has been resolved but I can't receive any data.
     $scope.dummyTasks={};
     $scope.getTask=function(){
  Task.query(function(data){
    $scope.dummyTasks=data;
  });
}();

But this method can receives data from the same factory

Comment: Good to see the progress... I am ready to assist, but it seems that now we have different issue. Could you set up a plunker to reproduce the error. I will try to help ...

Answer (score 0):

In a resolve section you need a generator function as value, so you probably will have to return the promise you are (hopefully ;-) ) generating and returning in Task.query().

In the code you wrote the function will not return anything.

```
resolve: {
           alltasks: function(Task){
             return Task.query(function(data){
               return data;
             });
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Radim Köhler. The [guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies) says:

> The `resolve` keyword MUST be on the `state` not the `views` (in case you use multiple views).